# Problem with Resolution in my Notebook

Tags: 14.04, display, resolution, screen

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my `Notebook Philco PHN14005`, but the screen is not good and it looks so big. Here is a screenshot of it:

[image: here]

How can I fix this problem with resolution display?

Answer (score 0):

Open Configuration (9th icon in your launcher), then Displays, and see if it lets you set a higher resolution.